# Haskell: (Sieve of Eratothenese) Getting the first n primes of the sieve

Tags: list, haskell, sieve

Let's say I have an expression such as:

```
[2] ++ sieve [3,5..] where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [i | i <- xs, i `mod` p /= 0]
```

How would I go about (in a function) taking the first *n* elements of this list? I'm aware of the `take` function but I can't figure out how to use it in this context.

I'm aware this expression creates an infinite list of primes. I'm trying to figure out to extract the first *n* primes.

Comment: `take n $ expression`? Note `[2] ++ s` == `2 : s`.

Comment: I've tried that, but am getting compilation errors.

Comment: @user3247014 If you get compilation errors for a particular piece of code, you should include precisely the code which gives the error, and the actual error. Note that `e where x = t` is *not* a valid expression - `where` is only valid in declarations. However, `let x = y in e` *is* a valid expression.

Comment: http://ideone.com/v2t6Mh

Comment: I see that works, n.m. But how would you go about taking say the first 1000 primes by only changing something inside a function?

Comment: @user3247014 Change `primes = ...` to `primes = take 1000 $ ...`? Keep in mind that due to laziness, there really is no difference between taking 1000 elements inside the `primes` function or outside.

Comment: @n.m. you should post your code sample as an answer...